# How can I find the randomly Xpath using Selenium?

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I am a newer in Selenium and use python to build it. Recently, I found a question which want to ask someone who can help me to figure it. The question is the Xpath I want to get is randomly, for example:

> '//*[@id="wiki-edit-wikiEdit26"]/div/div/div/div[2]/a[1]'
>
> '//*[@id="wiki-edit-wikiEdit27"]/div/div/div/div[2]/a[1]'
>
> '//*[@id="wiki-edit-wikiEdit28"]/div/div/div/div[2]/a[1]'

These three `xpath` are used on the same button, but the number after wikiEdit will be changed every time. Therefore, are there any way which can help me to run my script more smoothly? Thank you very much!

Here is my python code:

```
broswer.find.element_by_xpath('//*[@id="wiki-edit-wikiEdit26"]/div/div/div/div[2]/a[1]') .click()
```

Comment: do you want to change no. in wikiEdit ?

Comment: Please ass sample block of HTML

Comment: No, I just want to let my script run smoothly, because the xpath I mentioned will be changed when every time I get it. This would make my script be unstable

Comment: Either use matches or contains text with the string up to "wikiEdit" or else use other locator because id attribute with alphanumeric values will mostly change its values.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `matches` in xpath to do this,

```
broswer.find.element_by_xpath("//*[matches(@id, '^(wiki-edit-wikiEdit)[0-9]')]/div/div/div/div[2]/a[1]") .click()
```

so basically that matches the id anything starting `wiki-edit-wikiEdit` followed by numbers form `[0-9]`

Comment: Hi,
it seen have some error on this script as below.
 

File "C:\Auto\tttt.py", line 37 jira.find_element_by_xpath('//*[matches(@id, '^(wiki-edit-wikiEdit)[0-9]')]/div/div/div/div[2]/a[1]').click()
                                                                                                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: take care on the python strings. use double quotes for your xpath. I have updated my answer. Use that now.

Comment: I try the script you update but it still shows the error which means this is not a valid XPath. Thank you very much!

Comment: `syntax error` doesn't mean it is not a valid xpath. paste the code that you are trying

Answer (score 0):

You just need to format your string..

```
import random
# Random range 1 - 100
x = random.randint(1,100)

broswer.find.element_by_xpath(f'//*[@id="wiki-edit-wikiEdit{x}"]/div/div/div/div[2]/a[1]') .click()
```

Comment: Hi,
I also try your script, but it shows error as below. I do not the reason why make this happen. Please help me to figure out. Thank you very much!

**SyntaxError: invalid syntax**

Comment: Try this instead - broswer.find.element_by_xpath(r'//*[@id="wiki-edit-wikiEdit%s"]/div/div/div/div[2]/a[1]'%x) .click()

Answer (score 0):

You can use `starts-with` or `contains`

```
broswer.find.element_by_xpath("//*[contains(@id,'wiki-edit-wikiEdit')]/div/div/div/div[2]/a[1]").click()
```

Also, using such long xpath's is not recommended. Use `css-selectors` over `xpath`.

Comment: Sorry, because I am a newer, could you please give me the example of how to use css-selector. In addition, I have use your script but it shows error and can not get the response. 

CSS: 
#wiki-edit-wikiEdit1 > div > div > div > div:nth-child(2) > a:nth-child(1) > span